# How to Forwarding Requests from a Controller to Another Controller Programmatically in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, proxy, controller, forwarding

Nowadays, I've been making an API system and I've got stuck in a problem regarding forwarding requests.

In my API system, all of requests from users come to proxy controllers first, and then the requests are forwarded to real API versionized.

```
// proxy controller
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/proxy")
public class ProxyController {
  private static final String VERSION = "v1";

  @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String getUsers() {
     return String.format("forward:/%s/users", VERSION);
  }
}
```

```
// Real API controller
@RestController("v1UsersController")
@RequestMapping("/v1/users")
public class UsersController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ApiResultsResponse<Users> findUsers(@RequestParam userId, ...) { 
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...
    // return users found
  }
```

I've located the proxy controller because I could easily change the real api when some case happens like upgrading version of the api.

However, because I've used forwarding with String(in this case, `return String.format("forward:/%s/users", VERSION)`), I'm not sure whether the forwarded real api exist or not currently.

So I'd like to be sure this by calling the real api's controller method directly. If so, when the called method doesn't exists, I can notice this with compile errors. The problem is, I gotta synchronize parameters condition of real api handler with proxy's.(It's kinda dirty works.)

Is it possible to call forwarded controller method directly with using the same HttpServletRequest object?

Answer (score 0):

You could use spring HandlerInterceptorAdapter to intercept before call your controllers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solution will help you.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public void getUsers(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {

     String path = String.format("forward:/%s/users", VERSION);
     RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher(path);  
     dispatcher.forward(request, response); 

  }
```

Comment: Hmmm, Can I ask how this make me help? I've not got your point. @Seymur Asadov